# How to change Redux state from a path string?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have initial state like this:

```js
const initialState = {
  array: [
    {
      key: "value",
      obj: {
        key1: "value",
        key2: "value",
      },
      array: [
        {
          key: "value",
          obj: {
            key1: "value",
            key2: "value",
          },
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      key: "value",
      obj: {
        key1: "value",
        key2: "value",
      },
    },
    {
      key: "value",
      obj: {
        key1: "value",
        key2: "value",
      },
    },
  ],
  path: "",
  value: ""
};
```

Reducer:

```js
export const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SET_PATH":
      return {
        ...state,
        path: action.path
      };

    case "SET_NEW_VALUE":
      return {
        ...state,
        newValue: action.value
      };

    case "SET_NEW_BUILD":
      //What next?

    default:
      return state
  }
};
```

Action creators:

```js
const setPath = (path) => ({type: "SET_PATH", path});
const setNewValue = (value) => ({type: "SET_NEW_VALUE", value});
const setNewBuild = (path, value) => ({type: "SET_NEW_BUILD", path, value});
```

And i need to change this state after this dispatch using a path string and new value.

```js
dispatch(setNewBuild("array[0].obj.key1", "newValue");
```

Also the value can have form like this "obj: {key1: "newValue", key2: "newValue"}" hence will be created a new object.

How can i do this?

Comment: I think [this](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9) would get close to what you're looking for. But instead of string I use an array: `['array',0,'obj','key1']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example using the [set](https://gist.github.com/amsterdamharu/659bb39912096e74ba1c8c676948d5d9) helper:

```js
const REMOVE = () => REMOVE;
//helper to get state values
const get = (object, path, defaultValue) => {
  const recur = (current, path, defaultValue) => {
    if (current === undefined) {
      return defaultValue;
    }
    if (path.length === 0) {
      return current;
    }
    return recur(
      current[path[0]],
      path.slice(1),
      defaultValue
    );
  };
  return recur(object, path, defaultValue);
};
//helper to set state values
const set = (object, path, callback) => {
  const setKey = (current, key, value) => {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      return value === REMOVE
        ? current.filter((_, i) => key !== i)
        : current.map((c, i) => (i === key ? value : c));
    }
    return value === REMOVE
      ? Object.entries(current).reduce((result, [k, v]) => {
          if (k !== key) {
            result[k] = v;
          }
          return result;
        }, {})
      : { ...current, [key]: value };
  };
  const recur = (current, path, newValue) => {
    if (path.length === 1) {
      return setKey(current, path[0], newValue);
    }
    return setKey(
      current,
      path[0],
      recur(current[path[0]], path.slice(1), newValue)
    );
  };
  const oldValue = get(object, path);
  const newValue = callback(oldValue);
  if (oldValue === newValue) {
    return object;
  }
  return recur(object, path, newValue);
};
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore } = Redux;

//action
const setNewBuild = (path, value) => ({
  type: 'SET_NEW_BUILD',
  path,
  value,
});
const initialState = {
  array: [
    {
      key: 'value',
      obj: {
        key1: 'value',
        key2: 'value',
      },
    },
  ],
  path: '',
  value: '',
};
const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  const { type } = action;
  if (type === 'SET_NEW_BUILD') {
    const { path, value } = action;
    return set(state, path, () => value);
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
const App = () => {
  const state = useSelector((x) => x);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            setNewBuild(
              ['array', 0, 'obj', 'key1'],
              'new value key 1'
            )
          )
        }
      >
        change array 0 obj key1
      </button>
      <button
        onClick={() =>
          dispatch(
            setNewBuild(['array', 0, 'obj'], {
              key1: 'change both key1',
              key2: 'change both key2',
            })
          )
        }
      >
        change array 0 obj
      </button>
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(state, undefined, 2)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
};
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

The important bits are:

```
<button
  onClick={() =>
    dispatch(
      // path is an array
      setNewBuild(['array', 0, 'obj'], {
        key1: 'change both key1',
        key2: 'change both key2',
      })
    )
  }
>
  change array 0 obj
</button>
```

And in the reducer:

```
const { type } = action;
if (type === 'SET_NEW_BUILD') {
  const { path, value } = action;
  return set(state, path, () => value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`getState` gives you current state at action dispatch time, also, do notice that you dispatch actions as higher-order functions ( `UI-dispatch(action(payload => dispatch => dispatch({type, payload}))`

---

```
 //assuming { value } comes from UI and { path } refer to current stored data at state
 const action = value => (dispatch, getState) => 
        dispatch({type: "netNewData", value, path: getState().array[0].obj.key1}) ;


 const reducer = ( state = initialState, action) => {
  switch(action.type){
   case "setNewData":
      const { value, path } = action;
      return {...state, value, path}
   default: return state
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do that with only the `path` there's 2 approaches, remember that in Redux everything has to be immutable, so no direct mutations should be done.

- Easier approach: [immer library](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) that allows you to do mutating operations like `push` or using dot operator, but being immutable underneath.
- Difficult approach: use [spreads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) native JS spread operators for object and arrays, but you will understand better how things work.

I will leave the vanilla example, but if you prefer going with something straight forward you can use immer library.

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'setNewData': {
      const { array } = state;
      const { path, value } = action.payload;

      const index = path.match(/[\d]+/g);
      const objectPath = path.split('.').slice(1);

      const [elementToReplace] = array.slice(index, index + 1);
      _.set(elementToReplace, objectPath, value); // using lodash set helper here

      const newArray = [...array.slice(0, index), elementToReplace, ...array.slice()];

      return {
        ...state,
        array: newArray,
      };
    }

    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach updates the `ref`erence as it iterates through the path `key`s. Those `slices are because the setter must stop at the penultimate key to set the value on the parent.

E.g. `({d: 4}).d = 6` not `4 = 6`

```js
path = ['a','b','c','d'];
state = {a: {b: {c: {d: 4}}}};
value = 6;
// jsonpath setter:
path.slice(0, -1).reduce((ref, key)=>ref[key], state)[path.slice(-1)] = value;
// jsonpath getter:
console.log(path.reduce((ref, key)=>ref[key], state), state.a.b.c); // 6 {d:6}
```